# Error in cross server sqlcmd execution due to firewall issue

Tags: sql-server, firewall, database, database-administration, sql-server-2012

I have an application server with an IP of 10.107.0.100 and one database server on which SQL Server 2012 is installed, with an IP of 10.107.0.101.

Remote connections are made to this server, and the firewall is ON and the server is running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Now on my application server I am executing a batch file which remotely connects to the database server and creates my database and performs all operations which I want, but this only works when the firewall is OFF.

As soon as I turn the firewall ON, I get an error "remote connection are not allowed".

I googled it and it told to add port number to INBOUND RULES ON MY DB SERVER I added 1433 and 1444 ports to that but didn't help me.

So how can I solve this firewall issue?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server responds on a dynamic port by default.  If you want SQL to respond on 1433 you'll have to set it to do so.  [The perhaps less-than-intuitive part is that TCP Dynamic Ports value is set to 0 to turn it on, and to turn it off you have to delete the 0.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx)

[image]